# "list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

Should receive:

```
[[‘a’, ’m’], [’a’, ’n’], [‘b’, ’m’], [’b’, ’n’], [’c’, ’m’], [’c’, ’n’]]
```

Getting message error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Code

```
for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
        cartesian_list.append([lst1[i], lst2[j]])
```

Comment: Well, the error is telling what happens. You can't access `list['a']`.

Comment: I think the error message is clear.

Comment: Python's `for` loop is a `for each`; `for i in lst1:` iterates over the items in the list, not their indices...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a previous comment, the python for loop is an iterator over each element of the collection. Instead of C where it is usual to use a for loop to produce index values `for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)` which are subsequently used to fetch the value at that index from some array, the equivalent python code `for i in my_list:` will set `i` equal to the value produced by the iterator for that collection or generator. Since a list is an ordered collection you will get the standard sequential iterator behavior.

With that in mind, you can instead use the values of `i` and `j` directly to correct your code:

```
cartesian_list.append([i, j])
```

However, there is a simpler shortcut in python via itertools:

```
from itertools import product
cartesian_list = list(product('abc', 'mn'))
print(cartesian_list)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'm'), ('a', 'n'), ('b', 'm'), ('b', 'n'), ('c', 'm'), ('c', 'n')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate over a list in Python, the variable (in this case: i and j) will get assigned every element of the iterable object you pass to it.

Looking at your code and assumtion of output I suppose these lists are defined:

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['m', 'n']
cartesian_list = []
```

Keep in mind that every element of both lists is a string.

In your code you try to take index i (where i is a string!) of lst1. This is not possible. The 'Type Error' you are seeing is just Python telling you that i (and j, for that matter) is a string. It should be an integer to be used like this.

There are two main ways of fixing this:

```
for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
        cartesian_list.append([i, j])
```

This way you will have to change only a fraction of your code.
Another way of fixing the problem is to make i and j iterate over the indexes, like you intended them to do.

```
for i in range(len(lst1)):
    for j in range(len(lst2)):
        cartesian_list.append([lst1[i], lst2[j]])
```

Using this method, i will iterate over the theoretical list [0, 1, 2... len(lst1)-1]. Range() excludes the last value given, so it's safe to use only len() (which would give 3 when the last index is 2).

I hope I helped!